# Any way to convert this code to work in Powershell? Needed for Strapi to deploy to Heroku

Tags: linux, windows, unix, heroku, strapi

I'm trying to deploy a Strapi backend to Heroku, on their [docs](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/hosting-guides/heroku.html), they use this line of code:

```
heroku config:set MY_HEROKU_URL=$(heroku info -s | grep web_url | cut -d= -f2)
```

Of course this (grep and cut) don't work in powershell. Does anyone know an alternative way to enter this into powershell? Or if there is any docs relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use capturing feature of `-replace` PowerShell operand.

I don't know the specific format of heroku command, so I will only give a simple example.

```
> $web_url = "mysite.com"
> "mysite.com some information" -replace "$web_url (.+)", '$1'
some information
```

In the code above, `(.+)` captures the rest of the input string after the link and a space. `$1` references the captured string.

Pay attention that I used double-quotes for the first right-hand-side operand to expand `$web_url` into the regexp. On the other hand, single-quotes in the last operand to prevent powershell interpretting `$1` as a variable reference.

You can have more information about `-replace` operand and rexexp capturing from the following links:

- [about Comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#replacement-operator)
- [about Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.1#groups-captures-and-substitutions)

Note: Above code will apply the process to every line of input string:

```
> "mysite.com some information`nmysite.com some other information" -replace "$web_url (.+)", '$1'
some information
some other information
```